# Convert this textarea to rich html format via wp_editor

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor, wysiwyg

I have a texarea in a page that works like a charm, but I would like to convert the area to a html rich wp_editor. Could anyone tell me how to convert this textarea to a wp_editor field?? Thanks

```
 <textarea id="yith_vendor_biografia" name="yith_vendor_data[biografia]" rows="10" cols="50" class="large-text" placeholder="Write your mission statement here"><?php echo esc_textarea( stripslashes( $vendor->biografia ) ) ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4):

You basically have two options, using PHP or Javascript.

With PHP you would use the `wp_editor` function to output the textarea for you, and with Javascript you would convert the existing textarea with `wp.editor.initialize`.

Note there are slightly different settings available for each approach.

### PHP

[wp_editor function in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)

```
$id = 'yith_vendor_biografia';
$content = esc_textarea( stripslashes( $vendor->biografia ) );
$name = 'yith_vendor_data[biografia]';
$settings = array('tinymce' => true, 'textarea_name' => $name);
wp_editor($content, $id, $settings);
```

The `$settings` array can optionally be configured in more detail also:

```
$settings =   array(
    'wpautop' => true,              // Whether to use wpautop for adding in paragraphs. Note that the paragraphs are added automatically when wpautop is false.
    'media_buttons' => true,        // Whether to display media insert/upload buttons
    'textarea_name' => $name,       // The name assigned to the generated textarea and passed parameter when the form is submitted.
    'textarea_rows' => 10,          // The number of rows to display for the textarea
    'tabindex' => '',               // The tabindex value used for the form field
    'editor_css' => '',             // Additional CSS styling applied for both visual and HTML editors buttons, needs to include <style> tags, can use "scoped"
    'editor_class' => '',           // Any extra CSS Classes to append to the Editor textarea
    'teeny' => false,               // Whether to output the minimal editor configuration used in PressThis
    'dfw' => false,                 // Whether to replace the default fullscreen editor with DFW (needs specific DOM elements and CSS)
    'tinymce' => true,              // Load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array
    'quicktags' => true,            // Load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array. Set to false to remove your editor's Visual and Text tabs.
    'drag_drop_upload' => false     // Enable Drag & Drop Upload Support (since WordPress 3.9)
);
```

### Javascript

[wp.editor.initialize in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor#wp.editor.initialize)

```
<script>settings = { tinymce: true, quicktags: true }
wp.editor.initialize('yith_vendor_biografia', settings);</script>
```

You can also configure any of javascript settings, here is a full list of those:

```
settings = {

    tinymce: {
        wpautop  : true,
        theme    : 'modern',
        skin     : 'lightgray',
        language : 'en',
        formats  : {
            alignleft  : [
                { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: { textAlign: 'left' } },
                { selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignleft' }
            ],
            aligncenter: [
                { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: { textAlign: 'center' } },
                { selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'aligncenter' }
            ],
            alignright : [
                { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li', styles: { textAlign: 'right' } },
                { selector: 'img,table,dl.wp-caption', classes: 'alignright' }
            ],
            strikethrough: { inline: 'del' }
        },
        relative_urls       : false,
        remove_script_host  : false,
        convert_urls        : false,
        browser_spellcheck  : true,
        fix_list_elements   : true,
        entities            : '38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',
        entity_encoding     : 'raw',
        keep_styles         : false,
        paste_webkit_styles : 'font-weight font-style color',
        preview_styles      : 'font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform',
        tabfocus_elements   : ':prev,:next',
        plugins    : 'charmap,hr,media,paste,tabfocus,textcolor,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpview',
        resize     : 'vertical',
        menubar    : false,
        indent     : false,
        toolbar1   : 'bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv',
        toolbar2   : 'formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help',
        toolbar3   : '',
        toolbar4   : '',
        body_class : 'id post-type-post post-status-publish post-format-standard',
        wpeditimage_disable_captions: false,
        wpeditimage_html5_captions  : true

    },
    quicktags   : true,
    mediaButtons: true

}
```

[Source](https://wp-kama.ru/question/wp-editor-initialize)

Note also that if you are attempting to use these on the frontend of a site you will need to enqueue editor resources for that context with `wp_enqueue_editor();` (and if you want Media buttons you will need to also do `wp_enqueue_media();`)